# Hibernate causes problems when beans have cross refrence

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have hibernate beans say A, B and C. Here is the relation between them:

- A contains an object of B - many to one - lazy fetching
- B contains an object of C - many to one - lazy fetching
- C contains an object of SortedSet - one to many - lazy fetching

I am trying to get objects in this fashion A->getB()->getC()->getBs() and iterate over Bs using for loop.
Now after iterating when I call HibernateBeanReplicator.deepCopy() on A->getB(), it fails to fill the object graph and many of the fields of B remain null.

However if I change the relation like this A->getC()->getBs(), hibernateBeanReplicator works fine. Although my current app design does not allow me to change them like this.

Thanks a ton.
Suman